# How to remove thumb from custom renderer slider in Xamarin forms iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So i have created a custom renderer slider because i wanted to adjust the styling a bit and its width. I can work with the width just fine, but when i try to get rid of the thumbheader, it does not get removed.

I tried both `Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent.ToUIColor()` and `UIColor.Clear` but the thumb is still there. I intend to only display the bars, so i've set it to IsEnabled false in my xaml. Now i just need that thumbimage gone :)

Any idea what im doing wrong?

This is the iOS code renderer:

```
public class Slider_iOS : SliderRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
    {

        SetNativeControl(new MySlideriOS());
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}

public class MySlideriOS : UISlider
{

    public MySlideriOS()
    {
        this.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Clear;
        this.HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Fill;
        this.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Fill;
    }

    public override CGRect TrackRectForBounds(CGRect forBounds)
    {
        CGRect rect = base.TrackRectForBounds(forBounds);
        return new CGRect(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a image wrong show, and what you want show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the UIColor.Clear does not work, you can try to set a transparent image, that should do the trick

```
sliderImage.SetThumbImage(UIImage.FromFile("transparentIcon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have already run your code. I found that when the interface is initialized, the transparent background of the slider still exists, but he does not move with the slide.

You can try this , add `Control.ThumbTintColor` to here.

```
public class Slider_iOS : SliderRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Clear; //add here
        SetNativeControl(new MySlideriOS());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still show the thumb. If i uncomment "SetNativeControl(new MySlideriOS());" then it works, but then i do not get the buttonwidth functionality

Comment: Ok,it showing a bit strange. Do you add `Control.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Clear;` berfore `SetNativeControl(new MySlideriOS());` in code like my answer?